# Automatically update a field based off of data from another field

Tags: apex, trigger, scheduled-apex, field-update

Here's the scenario, we sell a Lite and Pro version of our product and a customer already has the Lite version and the fields on their account are filled out as shown below.

Product: Lite
Go Live Date: 4/1/13
Free Month: 4/1/13
1st Billable Month: 5/1/13
Current Revenue: $0
Future Revenue: $499

How could we get the revenue fields to automatically update themselves once the billable date passes. We would want the Current Revenue field to then update to $499. I'm still trying to learn Apex and haven't quite figured out the scheduling aspect yet.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you considered using formula field for the same ?Is current revenue later editable ?

Comment: I haven't considered a formula because I didn't think it a formula field would automatically update on its own unless the record was being re-saved. I need it to update on its own when the date passes. Could a formula field do that? Also, yes the Current Revenue field would be editable at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for apex, You can do it by writing a time-based workflow with a field update.

Comment: I thought about this however I need something more dynamic. I forgot to mention that the "Go live Date" could be any day within a month, however the "Free Month" and "1st Billable Month" fields would always be the 1st of the month. This means that I am unable to set a workflow for a fixed time before or after the "Go Live Date" since it is not always the same.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but your workflow trigger would be something like "0 days after 1st billable month" date as that is when you want to update the Current Revenue field. Otherwise, could you please elaborate on the relevance of "go live date"  for the use case. thanks!

Comment: Hmm... I didn't even think of driving the workflow off of the free month or 1st billable month fields. My brain was stuck on driving the workflow off of the live date itself. I'll give this a try and let you know if that works. Thanks!